# how to solve Uncaught exception solve in zend

Tags: php, zend-framework

```
return array('db' => array('driver'=> 'mysqli','dsn'=> 'mysql:dbname=zend;host=localhost',),'service_manager' => array('factories' => array('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter' => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory',),),
);
```

code of global.php

I just want to solve the error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'Zend\ModuleManager\Listener\Exception\InvalidArgumentException' with
>   message 'Config being merged must be an array, implement the
>   Traversable interface, or be an instance of Zend\Config\Config. NULL
>   given.

Can you please help me to solve this I want to create a page for the simple login page.also tell me the database connection way and configuration way. I'm new to zend.

Comment: Can you format the code you have shared, please?

Comment: This post may answer your question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16841797/zf-2-tutorial-application-config-being-merged-must-be-an-array

Comment: thanks for the replying this i have solve that error now it comes new error as bellow Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer::render: Unable to render template "application/index/index"; resolver could not resolve to a file ?
 how to solve this ?